# How to render table object from views.py using request send from ajax

Tags: django

**Can I send my object array from views.py to ajax and from ajax to html so I can get access to table data in html page.**

**HTML**

```
{% for job in job_details %}
<tr>
<td>{{job.id}}</td>
<td>{{job.user_id}}</td>
<td>{{job.job_name}}</td>
<td>{{job.start_time}}</td>
<td>{{job.end_time}}</td>
<td>{{job.job_url}}</td>
<td>{{job.creation_date}}</td>
<td>{{job.status}}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

**My.js**

```
 $.ajax( {
           //alert("in ajax");
           type:"POST",
           url:"/show_job_details/",
           data:{"test_name":'execution details'},
           success:function(objectfromtable){
```

**How I get here object from views.py. to use template here to show it in tabular format in my.html page**

}

**views.py**

```
def show_job_details(request):

     print "in job details"

     if request.POST and request.is_ajax():

                try:

    # fetching user and job details
                     print "in job details"
                     user_object_array=UserDetails.objects.all().order_by('email_id')
                     print "---------------------"
                     print user_object_array
                     job_object_array=JobDetails.objects.all().order_by('creation_date')

                     print "$$$$$ job details"
                     print job_object_array


                except IOError:
                        print "cant fetch data from jobdetails"

                return HttpResponse(job_object_array)



     else:
                raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make the table html it's own template. Then you can include it in other templates when returning `render` and also able to use `render_to_string` to include it in a json response. This allows you to make changes to the table template in one place, but have it change everywhere it's used rather than duplicating the logic.

table.html

```
<table>
{% for job in job_details %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{job.id}}</td>
        <td>{{job.user_id}}</td>
        <td>{{job.job_name}}</td>
        <td>{{job.start_time}}</td>
        <td>{{job.end_time}}</td>
        <td>{{job.job_url}}</td>
        <td>{{job.creation_date}}</td>
        <td>{{job.status}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

views.py:

```
import json
from django.template.loaders import render_to_string

def show_job_details(request):
    # Other logic
    job_object_array=JobDetails.objects.all().order_by('creation_date')
    data = {'html': render_to_string('table.html'), 'job_details':job_object_array}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Your javascript call

```
$.ajax( {
       type:"POST",
       url:"/show_job_details/",
       data:{"test_name":'execution details'},
       success:function(response){
           // Append response.html where ever you need it in your html.
           console.log(response.html);
       }
});
```

Comment: how to pasre it or use it in ajax block in my.js file.i have given my.js file code above.

Comment: @Ram I added the basic ajax post and success function. You'll have to append it to whatever element based on your need.